# Событие onclick перевести из Jquery на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите, пожалуйста, перевести из jQuery в классический JavaScript код:

```
$("#id1").on('click', 'input[type=radio]', function(){
     alert('hello');
}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: jquery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) работает довольно сложно, в Вашем коде он ловит событие click на всех существующих (и добавленых позже) элементах 'input[type=radio]' внутри '#id1', найти их можно через `document.querySelectorAll('#id1" input[type=radio]')` и поставить обработчик через `addEventListener` к каждому, но это не будет влиять на вновь добавленные элементы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("id1").addEventListener('click', function(e){
    alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: данный код. отличается от того что в вопросе. Здесь добавляется обработчик для элемента с id="id1" в то время как в вопросе - отслеживается клик по _input[type=radio]_

Answer (score 0):

Надо понять что к чему:
Ищется элемент `#id1`, слушается событие клика и, если целевой элемент `input[type=radio]`, выполняет `callback`.
Т. е. это реализация делегирования, что полезно при куче однотипных элементов, плюс - динамическое добавление элементов без особых колдунств.

Let's rock:

```js
function on(parent, evName, css, fn){
  // Ищем контейнер и вешаем слушатель на нужное событие
  document.querySelector(parent).addEventListener(evName, function(e){
    // Целевой элемент и ближайший возможный предок (или сама цель), удовлетворяющий селектору выборки
    let target = e.target,
        input  = target.closest(css);

    // Если элемент, подходящий под выборку, не найден или он вне контейнера - выходим!
    if (!input || !this.contains(input))
      return;
    
    // Да, всё подходит, вызываем функцию-слушатель, передавая this и объект события
    fn.call(target, e);
  });
}

on('#id1', 'click', 'input[type=radio]', function(e){
  console.info(this.value);
});




// Реализуем добавление блоков
let id = 0;
document.querySelector('#addGood').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let el = document.createElement('input');
  el.type = 'radio';
  el.value = 'Element N' + id++;
  
  document.querySelector('#id1').appendChild(el);
});

document.querySelector('#addBad').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let el = document.createElement('input');
  el.type = 'text';
  el.value = 'Element N' + id++;
  
  document.querySelector('#id1').appendChild(el);
});
```

```html
<div id='id1'>
  <input type='radio' value='One' />
  <br />
  <input type='text' value='А тут не работает!' />
  <br />
  <input type='radio' value='Two' />
  <br />
</div>
<hr />
<input type='button' id='addGood' value='Add radio block' /><br />
<input type='button' id='addBad' value='Add bad block' />
```